# Vue-router on apache, SPA in sub-directory, can only access pages by redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, vue.js, vue-router

So I have a Vue app for a client set up on an apache dev server. I am doing this to match the production environment. The app is in a subdirectory and I set the 'base' option on vue-router to match. If I navigate to my virtual host root it redirects properly, however navigating to the same address by typing the address in gives a 404.

Here is my router code:

```
const routes = [
  {path: '/', redirect: '/london' },
  {path: '/:city', component: homeView}
]

const router = new VueRouter ({
  mode: 'history',
  routes,
  base: '/subdir/'
})
```

I also have the relevant Apaache .htaccess in the 'subdir':

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

So if I navigate to "cityapp.local/subdir" it redirects to "cityapp.local/subdir/london", but if I type "cityapp.local/subdir/london" I got the apache 404 page.

Any thoughts or help would be appreciated!

EDIT: If I set my virtual host to include the subdir and removed the base option from the router, everything works fine. However, I cannot do this on production so I hope this info helps a little.

Comment: do you have the .htaccess file placed in your subdir folder?

Comment: Yes. I figured it out. See my answer below.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Jeez, was looking for a solution to this for a good chunk of time yesterday and today and just found the answer: [Vue help forum: Vue webpack project path change](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-webpack-project-path-change/4993/6)

Relevant code for anyone else that my find this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectoryName
RewriteRule ^subdirectoryName/index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subdirectoryName/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

I honestly tried something similar yesterday. I changed the RewriteBase to the subdir but not the rewrite rules! I'm bad at .htaccesss stuff :(

Comment: oh yes, the example in vue docs doesn't show use within subdirectories

Comment: I recently had the same problem and came across a great tool to help debug htaccess issues: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: My project was deployed in a subdirectory on an existing server with 404 handling that had to be maintained. To make the above solution work in this case add one additional RewriteCond to the existing two.`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdirectoryName/. [NC]`

Comment: Thanks for the link Cliff. This tool finally demystified what is going on in my htaccess file.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /jcafe/dist
RewriteRule ^jcafe/dist/index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /jcafe/dist/index.html [L]
</IfModule> I got 403 please help.

Answer (score 6):

It can be a bug with your apache version.

RewriteRule of "^$" broke between 2.2.21 and 2.4.2
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53929

You can use Fallback ressource instead of mod_rewrite in your apache config.
It works for me.

In **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName YourServerName
    DocumentRoot /var/www/yourApp/dist
    <Directory "/var/www/yourApp/dist">
        FallbackResource /index.html
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3):

i fixed this by adding FallbackResource /index.html in my site configuration...

the directory in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/{your domain}.conf

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/yourApp/dist
<Directory "/var/www/yourApp/dist">
    FallbackResource /index.html
</Directory>
```