# htaccess rewrite js/css files to subdirectory

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, vuejs2

I have a simple VueJS site that ive built and im deploying it to an apache server. I am having trouble with the .htaccess rewrite rules.

Right now it throws errors because index.html is looking for the files at the root(/) path instead of /v1/css or /v1/js. I want the url to NOT show the subdirectory, but to show as https://test.com. Then internally have the .htaccess point the /css, /js, /images, etc to /v1/css/, /v1/js/ etc...

apache server:

```
/
- v1
-.htaccess
  ---css
  ---js
  ---images
  ---index.html
  ---.htaccess
```

The .htaccess file in the root:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^$ /v1/ [L]
```

The .htaccess in v1 directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Comment: Does `Base` tag work for your? Try adding this to the header of your webpage `<base href="/v1/">` This will automatically correct your relative links location forexample: `<img src="foo.jpg">` will change its image path to `<img src="/v1/foo.png">`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working using the root directory .htaccess file only thanks to another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52119135/vue-router-on-apache-spa-in-sub-directory-can-only-access-pages-by-redirect)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) /v1/$1 [L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteBase /v1
  RewriteRule ^v1/index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /v1/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```